# Creating repeating counter on button click in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a counter what will start counting on Tap Start and will reset after Tap Ended. I am using DragGesture as there is no onStart like event on TapGesture. But the preblem of using DragGesture is if user started dragging after tapping the value changes dramatically! Any suggestion in different ways is welcome.

```
struct RepeatingButtonTest: View {
    
    @State private var isPressed = false
    @State var theNumber = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(theNumber)")
                .font(.title)
            Circle()
                .fill(isPressed ? Color.red : Color.blue)
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80, alignment: .center)
                .gesture(drag)
        }
    }
    
    var drag: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
            .onChanged { _ in
                isPressed = true
                theNumber += 1
                
                Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
                    if isPressed { theNumber += 1 }
                    if !isPressed {
                        timer.invalidate()
                        theNumber = 0
                    }
                }
            }
            .onEnded { _ in isPressed = false }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You creates new timer on every drag event, so you just need to add condition to do it once, like

```
var drag: some Gesture {
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
        .onChanged { _ in
            guard !isPressed else { return }   // << here

            isPressed = true
            theNumber += 1
            
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
                if isPressed { theNumber += 1 }
                if !isPressed {
                    timer.invalidate()
                    theNumber = 0
                }
            }
        }
        .onEnded { _ in isPressed = false }
}
```